# What do I need to do to resolve bundle org.eclipse.rap.ui cannot be resolved in eclipse helios?

Tags: java, eclipse-rap

I don't know what I have done wrong but it seems pretty major yet I can't figure it out. I'm using Eclipse Helios to create a RCP / RAP application. I downloaded and installed the RCP / RAP IDE and I could previously launch RAP applications (although there were some runtime exceptions about something missing). Now when I create a new plug-in project using the rap hello world template I get 49 errors which I can resolve down to about 4 but the bundle org.eclipse.rap.ui cannot be resolved has got me.

Answer (score 2):

by the looks of it, the RAP/RCP eclipse download did not include the required RAP target. I searched for the org.eclipse.rap.ui plugin, and its not in there. I would have expected it to be in a separate folder or something.
The RAP target can be obtained from here;
http://www.eclipse.org/rap/downloads/

I had to download a copy of the runtime and stick it locally in my file-system, and then create a new target from windows->preferences->plug-in->development->targets
and add a new RAP one, and point it to the downloaded folder.

in addition there seems to be an option to create a new target based upon a "software site" I tried by searching for "target" and selecting the Rap runtime target from the available software menu, and that seemed to work as well.

tldr;
I think the description of the RAP/RCP eclipse download is slightly misleading saying that all that is required to developer RAP/RCP apps is in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the RAP UI plugin is missing from your install.

First look at the plugins folder of your Helios install and check the presence of the `org.eclipse.rap.ui` plugin.

If not present, download again Helios RCP / RAP ide. It must be present otherwise there is a problem at eclipse.org but I am sure this is almost impossible ;-)

If present, open the plugin registry view Window -> Show View -> Other -> Plugin Dev -> Plugin registry and look for this missing plugin inside it.

If you see the plugin, right click on it and check Show Advanced Operations. Then right click again on it and select Diagnose. Here you should get information about the missing dependencies explaining why Eclipse can't find this plugin.

Hope this can help

Comment: Had already thought of that, and no the plugin is not present, even after downloading it again. I only have org.eclipse.rap.ui.themes and 3 others I cannot remember off the top of my head. I guess this is the problem but I don't know why it is missing. Any ideas?

Good tip about the plugin registry, I didn't know about that. :)

Comment: @Steiny I tried to download and ru nRAP Hello world and got the same error. I think now there is an issue at Eclipse package level, so I guess you should may be open one bug entry for that or at least look/ask into Eclipse forums for help (the forums are down for now ...) Hope this can help.